# SetSpan in an edit field for two strings merging in each other from top to bottom in Android?

Tags: android, background, spannablestring

I am working on an application where I have contacts chosen in the TO field of screen. I have used **new BackgroundColorSpan** to color the string of the names as shown in the picture.

How can I **separate the 2 strings from top to bottom** as shown in the figure?

Below I have mentioned the source code which I am using.

```
spanStr.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(getResources().
getColor(fonts.getSelectedContactBoxColor())), higlightedIndex.get(j),higlightedIndex.get(j+1)+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image]

Comment: You can try adjusting line spacing. If that does not help, you may need to implement your own replacement for `BackgroundColorSpan` that does not apply the background to the line spacing.

Comment: I have tried with the LINE SPACING, but its not working. What can be replacement of BackgroundColorSpan ? I am looking for that customization.

Comment: Well, [`BackgroundColorSpan` is fairly short](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.java). What you are seeing is apparently the stock behavior of setting `bgColor` on a `TextPaint`. You might research ways to control `TextPaint` better, as I do not know what options there are here, if any.